# Is there a VS Code extension or setting to alleviate useless index.js tab names?

Tags: visual-studio-code

Here's my current tab list, for reference:

[image]

I don't need to see `index.js` on any of these files, I need the parent folder name directly next to `index.js`, that's the useful information in the tab.

Is there a setting or extension which shoves `index.js` to the end of the tab, giving me useful tabs back?

I suppose in the mean time, I can use the `open editors` section of the navigator instead.

Comment: not implemented for now ... https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/41909

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You can use the "workbench.editor.labelFormat" option for this. I've set it to "short", now each file is followed by its directory.

Comment: That's the best I've been able to configure, too.

Answer (score 1):

A fix for this [is in Insiders v1.88](release notes link: https://code.visualstudio.com/updates/v1_88#_custom-labels-for-open-editors).  You can change your tab names to something like `/parentFolder index` using this value:

```
\${dirname} {filename}
```

in the setting:

```
Workbench > Editor > CustomLabels : Patterns
```

(setting ID `workbench.editor.customLabels.patterns`)

See more at [Provide api to access and change editor tab labels](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/41909#issuecomment-2009899492)