# The problem of nextjs and vscode, all file names are index.js

Tags: reactjs, visual-studio-code, next.js

since all the page files are named index.js, the file tabs section is full of index.jses, you can't figure out which file belongs to which page, you'll have to open and view the tab to learn that.

this kind of approach sucks, is there any solution to this?

[image]

---

before starting to use nextjs, I used to create two files, index.js and the file name I want, where index.js is just a placeholder file which exports the component from the other file. ex:

```
users/
  index.js
  users.js
```

#### users.js

```
export default function Users(){
  // ...
}
```

#### index.js

```
export { default } from './users.js'
```

at least, this shows users.js in the tabs' panel in VS Code, which makes a lot of sense.
[image]

You can't do that with nextjs however, because it will think it's a valid path.

Comment: @FabioNettis, no, my folder structure is not simple, this is just an example.

Comment: Your question does not clearly state that this is merely an example. Neither was it clear from the images **you have provided**. So quite rude to downvote.

Comment: @FabioNettis, please don't take it personally, my apologies for the misconception.

Comment: I agree that it sucks. It's even worse in newer version (app router)

Comment: Please see https://stackoverflow.com/a/78195425/836330 for a fix for this in Insiders v1.88.

Comment: @Mark, thanks I used the "workbench.editor.labelFormat": "short", it's good a little bit

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this will help you, but I asked the same question a few Minutes ago on the Nextjs Discord Server, and from my understanding "it's impossible" at the Moment [05.08.2023 DMY], and I don't know if they'll change it in the near Future.

[Link to the Question](https://nextjs-forum.com/post/1137437871381414078)

Answer (score -1):

Since your folder structure is rather simple and you are using the pages directory you could remove the folders and just name your files like you have the folders e.g `about.tsx`, `help.tsx` etc.